# Смайлики в чат

Tags: php

Я сделал чат на php+MySQL а как туда еще всунуть смайлики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый примитивный способ)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertSmile(smile)
{
    document.chatform.chatmassage.value += smile;
}        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="chatform">
<textarea name="chatmassage"></textarea>
</form>
<img src="" alt=";)" onclick="insertSmile(';) ')" />
<img src="" alt="%)" onclick="insertSmile('%) ')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я предполагаю, что ТС имел в виду графические.

Comment: Что ТС имел ввиду - известно только ему)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться услугами разметки HTML, подучить JS, написать CSS собрать все воедино и пользоваться полученными "вкусняшками".

Answer (score 0):

Сделай в обработчике выводимых сообщений обработку по регулярке, нужен какой-то шаблон смайла, типа :код_смайла:, и по этой регулярке все такие заменять на изображения, соответствующие коду.